# Material ui Select component with asynchronous data. How to use it in react hook form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui, react-hook-form

In my React application, I am using react-hook-form and Material UI. I have a situation like this. need to show a dropdown with a list of values. This list of values is getting from the API response. another API is getting the value previously stored. My problem is initially the dropdown is not getting selected with saved value.

what I have is :

```
const { data: allCountryList } = useGetCountryList(); // Fetching entire countrylist

const countryList = useMemo(() => { //Processing the countrylist
const list = allCountryList?.result?.countryList?.map((country) => ({
  label: country?.name,
  value: country?.code,
}));
return list;
}, [allCountryList]);

const fetchDetails = useCallback(async () => {
const response = await getProfileDetails(); // getting previously saved values

const {
  email = '',
 .........
  country = '',
} = response?.result?.user ?? '';
response?.result?.user?.companies;

return {
  email,
  .........
  country,
 };
 }, []);

const {
control,
setValue,
formState: { errors },
watch,
trigger,
getValues,
reset,
setError,
} = useForm<FormDataType>({
resolver: yupResolver(schema),
defaultValues: fetchDetails,
shouldFocusError: true,
mode: 'all',
});

   ......
return(
....................
<FormControl sx={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: '0' }}>
                  <Controller
                    name="country"
                    control={control}
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <Select
                        id="country"
                        label="country
                        aria-label="country"
                        required
                        displayEmpty
                        MenuProps={{ sx: { maxHeight: 200 } }}
                        {...field}
                        error={!!errors?.country?.message}
                        helperText={errors?.country?.message}
                        onChange={onCountryChange}
                      >
                        <MenuItem value="" disabled>
                          {t('fields.country')}
                        </MenuItem>
                        {countryList?.map((country, index) => (
                          <MenuItem value={country.value} key={`${country.value} - ${index}`}>
                            {country.label}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    )}
                  />
                </FormControl> 
      )
```

The output is :
[image]

How to solve this?